# What is the proper way of creating an scnassets catalog in xcode

Tags: xcode, scenekit

I'm new to SceneKit and I'm just curious as to what is the proper way of creating (let alone using) the .scnassets resource catalog that gets created in the SceneKit game project template in Xcode.

I know I can create a folder and give it the .scnassets extension, but it doesn't seem "proper".  Something tells me I've been pretty spoiled in the past.. Anyone?

A quick search on this SceneKit catalog has not yielded much.

Comment: that's exactly how it should be done :)

Comment: well, so be it then I guess :)

Answer (score 19):

It seems as easy as create an assets catalog and change the extension to .scnassets before saving.

Xcode will ask if you really want to change the .xcassets standard extension.

[xcode window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZOfN.png)

Comment: Do not create then rename, newer versions 9.4.1+ are crashing this way, create the assets catalog with the name "YourName.scnassets", Xcode will ask you if you're sure about it. Just confirm that.

Comment: `It seems as easy as create an assets catalog` - for new to XCode users it could be useful if you can add steps on how to create assets catalog as it is not obvious (for me for example)

Answer (score 19):

This is now available in three quick easy steps:

1. Choose File > New > File (or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> )
2. Select SceneKit Catalog
   [image]
3. Choose a name

Answer (score 1):

Create an Assets Catalog with the name "Your Name.scnassets", Xcode will ask you if you're sure then you just need to confirm that. (**Xcode 9.4.1+**)